# if$ x_n <y_n$ then series of $x_n < y_n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality

If i have two sequences $x_n$ and $y_n$, where$\sum_{n=1}^\infty x_n$ and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty y_n$ both converge, and for all $n
\in \mathbb{N}$ $x_n < y_n$, can I conclude that $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty x_n < \sum_{n=1}^\infty y_n?$$

or is that $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty x_n \leq \sum_{n=1}^\infty y_n?$$

Comment: the subscripts on the $x_k,y_k$ should match the index of the summation. and you don't need to add "for all n" since all of the $x_n$s and $y_n$s will appear in the sum anyway.

Comment: you're right, I'll fix that, but I think the for all n is necessary. its referring to the inequality not the summation. Am i right about that?

Comment: You're right about the "for all n".  Notice that the conclusion still holds if $x_n\le y_n$ for all n and $x_m<y_m$ for some $m\in\mathbb{N}$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Hint:** If $y_n > x_n$ for each $n$, then $y_n=x_n + \varepsilon_n$, where $\varepsilon_n = y_n - x_n> 0$ for each $n$. Then $$\sum y_n=\sum (x_n + \varepsilon_n) = \sum x_n + \sum \varepsilon_n$$

Answer (score 2):

The inequality can be made strict. To see this, let $A_N=\sum_{n=2}^{N} x_n$ and $B_N=\sum_{n=2}^N y_n$ for every integer $N\geq 2$. Since strict inequalities are preserved by finite sums, $A_N<B_N$ for all integers $N\geq 2$, and, since strict inequalities between the members of two convergent sequences are preserved as a weak inequality (in general) in the limit,
$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} x_n=\lim_{N\to\infty} A_N\leq\lim_{N\to\infty} B_N=\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} y_n.$$

Now comes the part that makes the weak inequality actually strict. Given that $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} x_n\leq\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} y_n$ and $x_1<y_1$, the conclusion is that
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x_n=x_1+\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} x_n<y_1+\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} y_n=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} y_n.$$

Answer (score 0):

No, from what data you provided, there is no way to conclude anything about the two sums, and here is why:

1. Yes bot $\sum x_n$ and $\sum y_n$ converge but to what values? This is the first problem that occures and most trivial.
2. Looking at the previous answer, it's a solid idea to look for a difference $x_n - y_n$ for each $n$ but then again the sum of those differences might not converge, which makes it useless.

Comment: If $\{\sum_{n=1}^N x_n\}_{N\in\mathbb N}$ and $\{\sum_{n=1}^N y_n\}_{N\in\mathbb N}$ both converge, then so does $\{\sum_{n=1}^N (x_n-y_n)\}_{N\in\mathbb N}$, and the limit of the difference equals the difference of the limits. This holds even if the series are not absolutely convergent, as long as they converge to finite real numbers.

Comment: That is true when the sums are finite. But in this case the limits are 1 to $\infty$. If the difference $x_i-y_i$ is constant for all i's then the sum of differences that doesn't converge.